# How to write the content of external .js files in a js.haml file (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view, haml, external

I'm using Ruby on Rails framework and I love it.

Until now I was using the `show.html.haml` for my views and everything worked fine. We wanted to add another option of supporting a GET request which consists the post-fix `.js`. For this purpose we added to the controller another parallel view named `show.js.haml`. 
The "magic" of Rails knows to route .html post-fix requests to the first and .js post-fix requests to the latter.

The problem is when a request gets routed to the `show.js.haml` view, I can't find a way to write **the content of external .js** files. All I get is the text itself (i.e. `<script src="myscripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`) but not the actual content of the file.

I've found a solution, which surely isn't optimal (performance, robustness etc): downloading the file to the server and use the following function:

```
!= File.open(Rails.root.join('public' , 'js',  'jquery-1.11.2.min.js'), 'rb').read
```

This is the only way I found to actually write the content of a .js file.

There must be a Ruby's elegant way to write the content of external .js files into a .js.haml file.

Any help would be appreciated here.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need the contents of the file or do you just need to be able to use it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want to use it, I need the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need this and which case this is a good idea for, but you can try this (untested):

```
# show.js.haml

// some javascript
= render file: Rails.root.join('public' , 'js',  'jquery-1.11.2.min.js')
// or
"#{render file: Rails.root.join('public' , 'js',  'jquery-1.11.2.min.js')}"
```

Of course this will only work for local resources accessible, but hey, that's what `<script src=` is for.

*EDIT*

In case of needing to store the contents of the file in a variable as a string, you can use `capture`. For remote files you can use [`open-uri`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html), which is part of Ruby's stdlib.

```
# show.js.haml
- content = capture do
- render file: Rails.root.join('public' , 'js',  'jquery-1.11.2.min.js')

# for remote files
- content = open('http://url.to/file.js').read
```

You can print the content later on:

```
= content
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but your answer won't help me extract the content of an external .js file.

Comment: This should print the content of the file on the js response, just as an "include" or "require" in many languages. Isn't that your question? Or maybe you are looking for the content of the file itself, as a "string" stored in a variable, so you can for instance manipulate it? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the content of the file itself, as a String. Any suggestions in this case?

Comment: Thanks, although I've already got a solution for local files. I need to find a way to do the same thing with external .js files... Any solution on this case?

Comment: Yes, it sure did! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the rails asset pipeline
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks for this, but I have already read the whole documentation before :)
The pipeline asset will surely allow me to use the external .js files, but I'm looking for something else - I need the extract the content from an external .js file (and use it later).